# Failed to register MzCOM.exe in Racket 6.6, what's the reason?

Tags: racket

I tried to use MzCOM but it was not successfully registered on my system.Tried to run `"C:\\Program Files\\Racket\\lib\\MzCOM.exe" /RegServer /v`(I installed Racket in that directory) but got a error message box "registration failed", which says the access is denied. Then run it as administrator but I didn't get any output and the MzCOM is still not registered.
P.S. Using Windows10 with Visual Studio 2015